# API for Company Data Enrichment Suggestions

Tags: dataset

I'm looking for API suggestions for enriching data on companies. Currently I use the Crunchbase API to look up a company's name or domain and I am trying to gather the domain/name (if I don't already have both), contact email (this one is a long shot), and the location of their headquarters.

This works incredibly well if Crunchbase has the company in their API, but I'd say this only happens about 25% of the time.

I'd love to get some suggestions on some free APIs that I could use along with Crunchbase. I'd also love to see if anyone has had positive or negative experiences with paid APIs!

Comment: For Web entities there's WHOIS.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Clearbit.com -- https://dashboard.clearbit.com/docs#company-api

Super comprehensive company lookup. Not free, but 50 free calls a month.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PySemantic - http://github.com/motherbox/pysemantic

There's a video too - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6z-18zP4hOA